# Creating a Python engine for debug within a parent Python engine

Tags: python, ironpython, sharpdevelop

I'm working on an IronPython script that is to be executed by another 3rd party application (Ansys HFSS) that provides a scripting interface for automation, etc.

Since I am also creating a graphical interface to the script I am using SharpDevelop (SD) as my IDE.  I would like to be able to take advantage of SharpDevelop's debugging tools but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I see that SD supports an 'Attach to process...' feature, which describes what I would like to do.  However, I don't have access to the parent Python engine as it being spawned by the 3rd party application.

I have found many solutions that talk about creating a Python engine within a C# application that can be connected to by an external debugger.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any cases where a Python engine is created within an existing Python engine.

Can anyone provide a solution?